# How to enable highlighter in pdf loaded in modal popup using jquery/java script/bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, bootstrap-modal

I have written a simple code using `Bootstrap` and `jQuery` to open the pdf file from  c:/users/download/ and its working fine. I don't know how to enable the highlighter in that opened/launched pdf file or how to allow the edit option in that pdf. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show us the code that you've tried, then maybe you'll get an answer or helpful indicator.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would also be good to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour